# Install mailparse on linux centos7

Tags: php, centos

Hi I'm trying to install mailparse for my php7.4.21 on my linux centos7 server but the documentation is not great and I'm no sysadin.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mailparse.installation.php states "In order to use these functions you must compile PHP with mailparse support by using the --enable-mailparse configure option". This is not very helpful but so far I've had to do the following:

```
// To install re2c:
> curl http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/r/re2c-0.14.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm --output re2c-0.14.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

> rpm -Uvh re2c-0.14.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

// I then installed mailparse
> pecl install mailparse

// I then modified php.ini to add the following:
extension=mailparse

// I then restarted apache
> systemctl restart httpd
```

But looking at my phpinfo output I cannot see mailparse listed.
What do I need to do next?

NOTE: I'm not sure I've actually "compiled PHP with mailparse" and I'm not sure how to apply "using the --enable-mailparse configure option".

Thanks
Abe

Comment: You haven't compiled PHP, you only installed an extension.

Comment: so how do you compile PHP [on centos]?

Comment: Don't. You don't want to compile stuff just to get a module. For a start, check `php -i | grep -C3 mailparse`. Further, instead of PECL, try to find a package for your OS, I'm pretty sure `rpm` allows searching for strings in package descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I ended up on https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser/blob/master/README.md that talks about using `sudo apt install php-cli php-mailparse` for Ubuntu systems, which after a little more effort I found that `yum install php-cli php-mailparse` was the equivalent for centos (and then restarting apache). This worked.

```
yum install php-cli php-mailparse
systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: When I search `yum search mailparse` all I get are PECL packages

php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64
php54-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php55-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php56-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php70-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php71-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php72-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php73-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php74-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php80-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64
php81-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php82-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64 
php83-php-pecl-mailparse.x86_64